# Chef - join method separator not recognized in erb template file

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

New to Ruby, I'm trying to list system users (on one row, comma separated) in an erb file, with the following code:

```
<% IO.readlines("/etc/passwd").each do |pwd| %><% user = pwd.split(":").first %><% users = user.split.join(",") %><%= users %><% end %>
```

but it's not joining with comma, just pasting the strings from the array consecutively with no spaces. same result if I leave the (",") off the join.

Any idea what's going wrong, or a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= IO.readlines('/etc/passwd').reject {|l| l.start_with?('#')}.map {|l| l.split(':')[0]}.join(',') %>
```

which is hideously ugly, but works.

This line `users = user.split.join(",")` is trying to split `user`, which is a string that only has the username of the current iteration.  And because you're writing the content of `users` (which is just `user` from that iteration) in each iteration, it just appended without a space. (`join`ing a single string means the character never gets introduced.)

For code like this, especially since it does not require either Chef's environment nor an ERB, it's easier to see what it's doing by putting it in its own script file or running with `irb` and then adding `puts` lines to debug.

Comment: Well, your hideous looks concise and functional to me. To your point, if I do put in a separator and split by it, I get the same result. e.g., `...<% user = pwd.split(":").first + "/" %><% users = user.split("/").join(",") %>...`. I trimmed it down because I saw that when I was omitting the join altogether (just splitting), I seemed to get correct output; `["root"]["bin"]["daemon"]...` But, your solution works great, thank you!